# Showing that inf$_{x \in M}||x||_{E} = \frac{1}{||f||}$ for $E$ a Banach space, $f \in E'$ and $M = \{x \in E: f(x) =1\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, supremum-and-infimum

Sorry if the question title is a bit cramped -- but I thought, in the end, it was short enough to fit. (If it's not standard notation, by $E'$ I mean the dual of $E$.)

I think the question is quite clear. My progress so far: I can show that the infimum is at least $\frac{1}{||f||}$ like this: for any $x \in M$, $|f(x)| \leq ||f||\cdot ||x||_{E}$, so by the definition of $f$, $1 \leq ||f||\cdot ||x||_{E}$, and so $||x||_{E} \geq \frac{1}{||f||}$ for any $x\in M$. Thus inf$_{x\in M}||x||_{E} \geq \frac{1}{||f||}$. But I'm not sure where to begin on proving the reverse inequality. I imagine you need to pick a specific element of $M$ which has norm $\frac{1}{||f||}$, which you should be able to do since $M$ is closed and convex, but I don't know how to go about finding that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all this assume $f\neq0$.

First, if $x\in M$ then $f(x)=1 ≤ \|f\|\,\|x\|$ and thus $\|x\|≥\frac1{\|f\|}$. The inequality holds when you pass to the infimum.

Next note that $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in E,\, \|x\|=1}|f(x)|$. For that reason for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a norm one vector $x_\epsilon\in E$ so that 
$$\|f\|≥|f(x_\epsilon)|≥\|f\|-\epsilon.$$
By making $\epsilon$ small we may assume that $f(x_\epsilon)\neq0$, then $\frac{x_\epsilon}{f(x_\epsilon)}\in M$ and you get:
$$\frac1{\|f\|-\epsilon}≥ \left\|\frac{x_\epsilon}{f(x_\epsilon)}\right\|≥\inf_{x\in M}\|x\|.$$
This can be done for any $\epsilon>0$ small enough, so take $\epsilon\to0$ to achieve the remaining inequality.

Comment: Great. That's perfect, thanks.

Comment: In the first part of the proof I believe it should be $\|x\| \ge \frac1{\|f\|}$ and hence $\inf_{x \in M} \|x\| \ge \frac1{\|f\|}$ which is the same inequality as obtained in the last part of the proof.

Comment: For the other inequality we can argue as follows: let $x \in X$ be arbitrary such that $f(x) \ne 0$. Then $\frac{x}{f(x)} \in M$ and hence $\left\|\frac{x}{f(x)}\right\| \ge \inf_{y \in M} \|y\|$ which implies $$|f(x)| \le \frac1{\inf_{y \in M} \|y\|}\|x\|$$
and hence $\|f\| \le \frac1{\inf_{y \in M} \|y\|}$, or $\frac1{\|f\|} \ge \inf_{y \in M} \|y\|$.

Comment: You are right, I had switched the first inequality so the second just showed the same thing again. I corrected the second one.